# Delete selected items from array / list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown

```
 <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Choose workers'" [data]="allWorkers"
                        [(ngModel)]="workers.selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                        (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
                      </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
                      {{selectedItems}}
```

I got my workers from api

```
allWorkers: string[] = [];
```

in my ngOnInit

```
this.workersService.getUsers().subscribe(
  (val: any[]) => {
    this.allWorkers = val.map(user => user.name + ' ' + user.city);
    console.log(this.allWorkers);
  }
)
```

all works fine but..
If I got

```
  onItemSelect(item: any) {

  }
```

I want to delete value from list if is selected

So if I have input:

- Name Surname
- Name Surname2
- Name Surname3

and I select Name Surname2
I want to have only to choose

- Name Surname
- Name Surname3

I tried something like this

```
onItemSelect(item: any) {
 const index = this.allWorkers.indexOf(item, 0);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.allWorkers.splice(index, 1);
    }
    }
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: please get rid of your any types and replace them with whatever type is needed (if you use a good editor like VS Code, it will even show you what type will be inserted), it will make your life so much easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the filter method :

```
this.allWorkers = this.allWorkers.filter(worker => worker !== item);
```